# 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED) Error for WIA dll file on local host IIs of asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, wia

I used WIA.dll to my web application for image scanning. It works fine under visual studio . But, when i hosted this application to my local IIS and ran I am getting following error.

> "Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {E1C5D730-7E97-4D8A-9E42-BBAE87C2059F} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))."

It does not throw error if my application run either user my account name or if I select "local system" instead of "ApplicationPoolIdentity" from Identity option of DefaultAppPool. This application will be used by other users.

I searched in google a lot but I did not get any solution. 
If anybody knows solution, please share me. I am totally stuck. Any kind of hint/solution is appreciable.

Comment: Have you tried running it under "local system" instead of "ApplicationPoolIdentity"?

Comment: bur for serious, [This](https://forums.iis.net/t/1207210.aspx) looks like it might be a good lead.

Comment: Have you get any solution for this?. I am also facing same kind of error.